# Getting an exception when starting a Spring-boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception

I'm getting the following exception when I run the app

Could someone advise what might be the issues?

```
Exception in thread "task-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:509)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getProperties(SessionFactoryImpl.java:503)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.findDataSource(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:105)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:97)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.access$100(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:50)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.lambda$postProcessEntityManagerFactory$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:


Parameter 0 of constructor in ru.javamentor.ecommerce.service.impl.ReadWriteServiceImpl required a single bean, but 4 were found:
- productCategoryDaoImpl: defined in file [D:\Project\ecommerce\target\classes\ru\javamentor\ecommerce\dao\impl\ProductCategoryDaoImpl.class]
- productDaoImpl: defined in file [D:\Project\ecommerce\target\classes\ru\javamentor\ecommerce\dao\impl\ProductDaoImpl.class]
- roleDaoImpl: defined in file [D:\Project\ecommerce\target\classes\ru\javamentor\ecommerce\dao\impl\RoleDaoImpl.class]
- userDaoImpl: defined in file [D:\Project\ecommerce\target\classes\ru\javamentor\ecommerce\dao\impl\UserDaoImpl.class]
```

ReadWriteServiceImpl class:

@Service

public class ReadWriteServiceImpl<T, PK> implements ReadWriteService<T, PK> {
private final ReadWriteDao<T, PK> readWriteDao;

```
@Autowired
public ReadWriteServiceImpl(ReadWriteDao<T, PK> readWriteDao) {
    this.readWriteDao = readWriteDao;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void persist(T t) {
    readWriteDao.persist(t);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void update(T t) {
    readWriteDao.update(t);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void delete(T t) {
    readWriteDao.delete(t);
}

@Override
public boolean existsById(PK id) {
    return readWriteDao.existsById(id);
}

@Override
public T getByKey(PK id) {
    return readWriteDao.getByKey(id);
}

@Override
public List<T> getAll() {
    return readWriteDao.getAll();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please show ReadWriteServiceImpl

Comment: Yeah, sure. Sorry

Comment: You cannot inject the generic ReadWriteDao you have either use a concrete type or qualifiy it by name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the reason for exception is clear:

There are 4 candidates for injection to `ReadWriteServiceImpl` and spring doesn't know which of the beans to inject:

```
public ReadWriteServiceImpl(ReadWriteDao<T, PK> readWriteDao) {
    this.readWriteDao = readWriteDao;
}
```

There are 4 candidates  - implementations of `ReadWriteDao` and spring lists them all in the exception...

There are three ways you can go with in this case:

1. Use Concrete type (or create an interface for that concrete implementation and inject by that interface so that spring won't be confused)
2. Use `@Qualifier` annotation as a hint to spring framework what to inject
3. Use `@Primary` annotation if you think that one repository should be used "by default" to resolve confusions like this.

Answer (score -1):

It showed me the error because I was writing wrong on the path

```
@GetMapping(myEndpoint+ "/${id}")
```

I should have written:

```
@GetMapping(myEndpoint+ "/{id}")
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question.